# Are reference types stored contiguously in Memory<T> in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, performance, memory

If I use memory to store a list of objects, there is no indirection when accessing them? If this is so, why not use memory instead of normal array always?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/memory-and-spans/memory-t-usage-guidelines) describes in detail how `Memory<T>` works.

Comment: I did check the docs, but there isn't an answer to my question. Or I don't understand.

Comment: Read that part of the article starting with the topic "Usage Guidelines."

Comment: My understanding of c# must be poor, because I still don't know if I make a Memory<T> where T is a reference type, if the Memory<T> is holding buffer of references, or buffer of actual objects. Sorry if its really obvious but I'm not getting it. I did read that section...

Comment: I think you might be getting hung up on "reference types."  It doesn't matter.  What does matter are things like "`Memory<T>` objects are stored on the stack," and there are several rules in that section of the documentation governing its use.  It should therefore be obvious that `Memory<T>` is not suitable for "ordinary" usage, its contiguousness (or lack thereof) notwithstanding.

Comment: Keep in mind that Memory<T> can represent types of contiguous memory beyond arrays alone. In addition, if you wanted to pass a _slice_ of the array rather than the entire array, and you cannot use a Span<T>, Memory<T> is your friend.

Comment: There is a lot of answering going on in the comments, against this site's [guidelines](https://prnt.sc/RfK7kkKxohGr "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.")!